# Не могу запустить проект на C++ через cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Есть проект по этой ссылке, мне нужно его запустить: https://github.com/PathPlanning/LIAN. У меня установлена Visual Studio 2019. Я пытался делать по инструкции, которая там через cmd:

[image: запуск проекта]

Моя cmd не видит эти команды. Значит в переменой PATH их нет, а как прописать не знаю.
После этого зашёл в VS и там нашёл в файл -> открыть -> CMAKE. Таким способ всё вроде бы правильно загрузилось, он сам всё сделал, видно, что проект открылся. Я запускаю проект и вылезли такие ошибки.
[image: Ошибки запуска проекта]

Как я понял, ему нужен нужно передать аргумент для запуска проекта. Не знаю, куда и как правильно его добавить

Comment: У них там CMakeLists.txt написан строго под GCC (или MinGW). Может помочь убрать из него 3 и 4 строчки.

Comment: Тут наверное проще будет сделать из этого кода новый студийный проект.